# Triggering a FLASH Event function

Tags: php, javascript, flash, actionscript

I am trying to build a simple application. The first phase is selecting to upload a file from the user desktop or from the site's gallery.

The question is if the user chose to upload from the gallery, say, go to an PHP page gallery, choose a photo and then redirected to the Flash app. How would you trigger the Flash up to know there was an image chosen and it should load it?

Does PHP send a variable or create an XML based on a choice and pass it via Flash variable, or does it need JavaScript to tell Flash that if the Flash var is not empty run this function? Could you please give  a sample script I could work on?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you starting the upload process outside of Flash when you want to use the file inside of the Flash application? Use FileReference to initiate the file upload, save the image name locally and have the php script you hand the file off to store the file in a known place, then listen for the Complete event. From there, you should be able to load the file into Flash from your server using the path "KnownDirectory/SavedFileName" with URLLoader.

Comment: Hi Stever. Thanks for the reply. The event will start with the PHP gallery not Flash. Pick an image from the gallery , php redirects to flash page. Flash loads image--that's my question. I think what you are describing is an event initiated with Flash. I am kinda familiar with that but it does not answer my question. You see there's 2 options choose from the desktop (which you described) and a splash page which let's you choose from the gallery before going to the flash application. Help would be appreciated

Comment: As long as the image is stored somewhere that flash can access, I would pass the url in using FlashVars when you load the Flash Page. Have the server side script that constructs the host page add the appropriate FlashVar.